# Is yelling or screaming while giving islamic lecture permissible?

Tags: practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, khutbah

So i know from my knowledge when imam has to give islamic lecture or khutba, he needs give it normally or nicely. but however in my country **Bangladesh**, not all but some of the imam or sheikhs give khutba very harshly sometimes insulting some people, and sometime start yelling.

So i show them some of the verses that says to give speech nicely not yelling as i believe that.

Like this one:

> So by mercy from Allah , [O Muhammad], you were lenient with them. And
> if you had been **rude [in speech] and harsh in heart**, they would have
> disbanded from about you

Verse (3:159)

but they give evidence by quoting a hadith.
and says that messenger (Peace be upon him) used get angry and rasie his voice when giving khutba.
That hadith is this

> It was narrated that Jabir bin 'Abdullah said: "When the Messenger of
> Allah (ﷺ) delivered a sermon, his eyes would turn red, he would raise
> his voice and he would speak with intensity, as if he were warning of
> an (enemy) army, saying, 'They will surely attack you in the morning,
> or they will surely attack you in the evening!' He would say: 'I and
> the Hour have been sent like these two,' and he would hold his index
> and middle finger. Then he would say: 'The best of guidance is the
> guidance of Muhammad. The most evil matters are those that are
> newly-invented, and every innovation (Bid'ah) is a going astray.' And
> he used to say: 'Whoever dies and leaves behind some wealth, it is for
> his family, and whoever leaves behind a debt or dependent children,
> then they are both my responsibility.'"

Grade:   Sahih (Darussalam)

Sunnah.com reference     : Book 1, Hadith 45

English translation  : Vol. 1, Book 1, Hadith 45

Arabic reference     : Book 1, Hadith 47

So my question is,

**Is it true that Muhammad (ﷺ) Used to give every khutba this way, and is it allowed to yell and talk harshly while giving khutba?**

Comment: At least there's a hadith describing the prophet's ... I'd say state ... when holding a sermon ... and if I remember well it says like he looks like - what one could conclude as - his face shows traces of anger and his speech is as if he is addressing an army going out to fight. Mainly I observed the behavior you described or a similar behavior from some middle eastern preachers more than others.